# I am getting valueError when executing migrate

Tags: python, django, wagtail

So I am new to Django and I am using a guide to do an easy e-commerce website.
The problem I have is that I keep getting an ValueError and I am not sure how to fix this.
This is my manage.py file

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rdewebsite.settings.dev")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And the error  I am getting is here:

```
Ernestass-MacBook-Pro:rdewebsite ernekz$ python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 60, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/ernekz/Desktop/Python/rdewebsite/rdewebsite/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.urls import password_reset as wagtailadmin_password_reset_urls
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/password_reset.py", line 3, in <module>
    from wagtail.admin.views import account
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/account.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wagtail.users.forms import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/users/forms.py", line 24, in <module>
    from wagtail.utils import l18n
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/l18n/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .maps import tz_cities, tz_fullnames, territories
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/l18n/maps.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .translation import L18NMap, L18NListMap
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/l18n/translation.py", line 50, in <module>
    _trans = Trans()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/utils/l18n/translation.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.set(getdefaultlocale()[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 568, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Django version is 2.1.3
Python version is 3.7.0
Also I tried using these in my /.bashprofile but it did not helped me at all

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Maybe some of you had similar error. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a line like `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'something'` in your project's settings file? What is it set to?

Comment: @gasman Yes I do, its written

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

Comment: Maybe this is a typo but in your question you write `/.bashprofile` but is need to be `~/.bash_profile`. And you need to apply changes `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE to launch your server? Or just directly from Terminal using the command-line?

Comment: @JonhyBeebop Sorry that was my Typo

Comment: @dirkgroten just directly from Terminal

Comment: And `printenv` shows these two variables correctly set?